# How to setState only when "map" loop is finished?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, promise, setstate

I send some http requests and after the Promises have solved I need to loop through the array and to do some async things. I want to leave the function asynchronous but I need to execute setState only after "map" loop is finished:

```
fetchData = () => {
 let data = [];
 let tickets  = http.get('/api/zendesk/tickets'),
     users    = http.get('/api/zendesk/users'),
     items    = http.get('/api/orders/items'),
     reqTypes = http.get("/api/support/requests");

 Promise.all([users,tickets,items,reqTypes])
  .then(values => {
    console.log(values);
    let usersArr = values[0].data.users,
      ticketsArr = values[1].data.tickets,
        itemsArr = values[2].data,
      requestArr = values[3].data;

    data = ticketsArr.map((ticket,key) => {

      let id = ticket.custom_fields.find(field => field.id === productions_fields.order_id || field.id === develop_fields.order_id).value;

      id === null ? ticket.Items = [] : ticket.Items = itemsArr.filter(item => item.order_id === parseInt(id));

      ticket.Requests = requestArr.filter(request => request.id === ticket.id);
    })

    this.setState({tickets:data})

  }).catch(err => console.log(err))
 }
```

Is it possible to do or I need to make sync loop like "for"? [image: Here is the screen:]

Comment: what is the issue with current code? also inside map which action is async?

Comment: I get an array of "undefined objects" when I print the state...I think 'filter' method is async, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I get an array of "undefined objects", Why?

Because you are not returning anything inside map body, and by default it returns `undefined`.

Check this snippet:

```js
let a = [1,2,3,4].map(el => {
   console.log('el = ', el);
})

console.log('a = ', a);   //array of undefined values
```

If you wants to modify the existing array, then use `forEach` instead of `map`.

Like this:

```
ticketsArr.forEach((ticket,key) => {
    let id = ticket.custom_fields.find(field => field.id === productions_fields.order_id || field.id === develop_fields.order_id).value;
    ticket.Items = (id === null) ? [] : itemsArr.filter(item => item.order_id === parseInt(id));
    ticket.Requests = requestArr.filter(request => request.id === ticket.id);
})

this.setState({ tickets: ticketsArr })
```

Comment: check the solution by using `forEach`, to modify the existing array we should use `forEach` not `map` :)

Comment: glad it helped you :)

Answer (score 1):

`Array.prototype.map` expects you to return how each element should be in its final form. Right now you are not returning anything, hence every element becoming `undefined`.

```
data = ticketsArr.map((ticket,key) => {
  let id = ticket.custom_fields.find(field => field.id === productions_fields.order_id || field.id === develop_fields.order_id).value;
  id === null ? ticket.Items = [] : ticket.Items = itemsArr.filter(item => item.order_id === parseInt(id));
  ticket.Requests = requestArr.filter(request => request.id === ticket.id);
  return ticket // <- this
})
```